# BigQuery Join On - Error: Unexpected

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I repeatedly get

`Error: Unexpected. Please try again.`

with this query:

```
SELECT Pollen.start, DNase.start, DNase.DNasecleavage
FROM   DNAse_raw_seq.DNAse_raw_seq_Chr1_table AS DNase
JOIN   DNAse_raw_seq.polleninput AS Pollen
       ON DNase.start  = Pollen.start
       where Pollen.GeneID contains "At1";
```

Yesterday I used the same query on a similar table2 which worked fine.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: And what error would that be?

Comment: The "standard" :)

Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.

Comment: @juergend: the error message actually reads "Unexpected. Please try again".

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

The functioning query reads like this

```
SELECT Pollen.GeneID, Pollen.start, DNase.DNasecleavage
FROM   DNAse_raw_seq.DNAse_raw_seq_Chr1_table AS DNase
JOIN   DNAse_raw_seq.polleninput AS Pollen
       ON DNase.start = Pollen.start
       where Pollen.GeneID contains "At1";
```

I was not allowed to SELECT DNase.start....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Pollen.start, DNase.start, DNase.DNasecleavage
FROM   DNAse_raw_seq.DNAse_raw_seq_Chr1_table AS DNase
JOIN   DNAse_raw_seq.polleninput AS Pollen
       ON DNase.start  = Pollen.start
       where Pollen.GeneID contains "At1";
```

You want to use where on "Pollen.GeneID" but you didn't selected it.
You can fix it by adding it to the select. Like this:

```
SELECT Pollen.GeneID, Pollen.start, DNase.start, DNase.DNasecleavage
FROM   DNAse_raw_seq.DNAse_raw_seq_Chr1_table AS DNase
JOIN   DNAse_raw_seq.polleninput AS Pollen
       ON DNase.start  = Pollen.start
       where Pollen.GeneID contains "At1";
```